# How to test and compare previous value and new value in postman?

Tags: javascript, api, testing, postman

I'm currently testing API requests. I'm dealing with a small problem.
Let's say I own a /Balance request. Let's say my current balance is 10.
I have made another request to my API to spend some of my balance and now it's 8.
How can I check through postman testing if my API value has changed from 10 to 8. How can I let

```
``
pm.test("Chechking clients balance ", function () {
let  balance = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(balance.BTC).to.eql(balance.BTC);
})
``
```

How do I find that previous balance before transaction?

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is that your request to modify the balance should return the old/new balance and you could test to verify it's accurate.

My second suggestion is that could use Postman variables. The logic will be:

1. Make your first request to get the current balance. Store the result in a variable.
2. Make your second request. If successful, update the balance variable to what you expect it to be.
3. Make your third request for current balance and verify it matches the data in your variable.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to fully understand your usecase/ workflow.

Anyhow, you can save values in environment variables, eg.

```
pm.environment.set("initialBalance", balance.BTC);
```

You then can later access that variables via

```
pm.environment.get("initialBalance");
```